# How to fix NoClassDefFoundError error with Aquillian

Tags: jboss-arquillian, wildfly-10

Hi I set up Arquillian with Wildfly 10 embedded, which is loaded into the target folder.

I see two mistakes at the moment:

```
Cannot not load JBoss LogManager. The LogManager has likely been accessed prior to this initialization.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/remoting3/spi/ConnectionProviderFactory
```

The first one I hope I can ignore. The second one I can't solve. Any idea why?

The ejb has dependency to four external ejbs over JNDI. In the arquillian.xml I mentioned nothing about this dependency.

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

<container qualifier="wildfly10" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="jbossHome">target/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/</property>
        <property name="modulePath">target/wildfly-10.0.0.Final/modules</property>
    </configuration>
</container>

</arquillian>
```

Where does the second error comes from? How can I solve it?

Thanks,
Markus

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved it was a Maven exclusion problem. :-(